# What path should I give as destination src at c9.io

Tags: c9.io

I dont have any problem manipulating the files that I have in my workspace, but on the other side, I have a code for uploading an image to a folder and I don't know what path to give.
In my original code when I was running it with xamp server the path was :

```
$destination = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\images\\";
```

What should I change it into so that I can save my images there?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was quite silly of me asking that.
For anyone that his brain stopped after hours of coding this is the answer :

`$destination = "images/";`